# GO_BACK on react navigation nested is not work

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-navigation-v6

Im using `react native v63` and `react navigation v6`.

I have 3 Bottom tab screen and 2 other screen

Tab screens :

- home
- category
- profile/singin

Stack screens :

- splash
- detail

When I navigated on tab screens or use `navigation.goBack()` everything is ok, but when I navigate to `detail` screen and navigated to one of `tab` screens like `category` or `profile` with button and use `back` for navigated to previous screen, that navigated to one of tab screens

For example :

Navigate from home -> detail -> profile, and use goBack() that navigated to home not detail

Or

Navigate from category -> detail -> profile, and use goBack() that navigated to category not detail

This is my code :

App.js:

```
<NavigationContainer
  linking={deepLinking}
}}>
  <stack.Navigator
    initialRouteName={initialState}
    screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <stack.Screen name="SPLASH" component={Splash} />
      <stack.Screen name="HOME" component={TabNavigator} />
      <stack.Screen name="DETAIL" component={Detail} />
  </stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

TabNavigator component:

```
<Tab.Navigator
    tabBar={(props) => <TabBar {...props} setTabBarLabel={setTabBarLabel} />}
    initialRouteName={'HOME'}
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
      tabBarHideOnKeyboard: tabBarLabel === 'Profile'
    }}
    backBehavior={'history'}
  >
    <Tab.Screen 
      name='USERPROFILE' 
      component={UserProfile} 
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: userData.name ? 'Profile' : 'SignIn/SignUp', 
      }}
      initialParams={
        {jwt: userData?.jwt} 
      }
      listeners={
        tabBarLabel === 'signIn/signUp' 
        ? {
            tabPress: (e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              setModalShow(true)
            },
          }
        : null
      }
    />
    <Tab.Screen 
      name='CATEGORY' 
      component={Category} 
      options={{tabBarLabel: 'Category'}}
      initialParams={{enVal: 'food'}}
    />
    <Tab.Screen name='HOME' component={Home} options={{tabBarLabel: 'Home'}}/>
  </Tab.Navigator>
```

Im using navigation from detail to profile like this:

`navigation.navigate('HOME',{screen: 'USERPROFILE', initial: false, params: { jwt }})`

And back : `navigation.goBack()`